# Can anybody tell me what this problem is about?

Tags: calculus, translation-request, mathematical-russian

This is a calculus problem. I don't know Russian.

> Показать, что существуют последовательности, расходящиеся в $+\infty$
>   (сходящиеся к нулю) и несравнимые с точки зрения скорости стремления к
>   $+\infty$ (сходимости к нулю).

Comment: Show that there are sequences, divergent in + ∞ (converging to zero) and the incomparable in terms of rate of convergence to + ∞ (convergence to zero.)

Comment: That's what Google translate gives me. You'd get a better answer if we knew the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that there exist sequences which diverge (namely limit of sequence equals $+\infty$) (or converge to 0) and these sequences aren't compareble with respect to rate of convergence (or rate it goes to infinity with(i.e. diverge)). Is my wording clear?I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: Well, that's *exactly* what I thought it said, yet I couldn't make any sense of it...sorry.

Comment: @unknown That's O.K. Thanks.

Comment: For example 1/n and 1/(n^2). limit equals 0 for each sequence. but their ratio equals n. therefore the limit of their ratio equals infinity, i.e. these sequences have different rates of convergence.  If the ratio equals 1 then sequences're called equivalent